# <ion-back-button> not showing despite having history in navigation stack Ionic4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am just starting with Ionic and have the very basic problem that the  is not showing automatically, even after having history in the navigation stack.

So first of all my app.html

```
      <ion-header>
                                <ion-toolbar style="background-color: #1c443a"
                                     color="#1c443a">
                                <ion-buttons slot="start">
                                       <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
                                </ion-buttons>
                                <ion-title>
                                </ion-title>
                        </ion-toolbar>
                </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
           <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" style="margin-top: 75px;"></ion-router-outlet>
    </ion-content>
<app-heu-ionic-menu-sidebar>
        </app-heu-ionic-menu-sidebar>
```

then the sidebar component where I have a list of  each representing a link to a page in the app.

```
     <ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="main-content">
  <ion-header>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list id="pages-list">
      <ion-list-header>Pflege</ion-list-header>
      <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of pages; let i = index">
        <ion-item (click)="selectedIndex = i" routerDirection="forward" [routerLink]="[p.url]"
                  lines="none" detail="false" [class.selected]="selectedIndex == i">
          <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

Now clicking on any  produces the right behavior of navigating to a ceratin page. However the  never shows. I tried to programmatically pop the latest page in navigation stack and it works and takes me back, which means the navigation history is correctly setup.

PS: This happens to be my first question on Stackoverflow, remarks to formatting the question are welcome. Also, remarks regarding anything in my HTML outside the scope of the question are welcomed as I am fairly new to Ionic and would appreciate any hints!

Comment: You should use your `ion-back-button` inside your page. Not in `app.component`.

Answer (score 0):

Change app.html and should be

```
<ion-app>

  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar style="background-color: #1c443a" color="#1c443a">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title>
      </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <app-heu-ionic-menu-sidebar>
    </app-heu-ionic-menu-sidebar>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" style="margin-top: 75px;"></ion-router-outlet>

</ion-app>
```